# Generating complex HEX ID's with PHP

Tags: php, hex

How are ID's like the one below generated:

`427B72E0A884462C8200B0002EF6BA549D78D0F0`

---

Is it a number ID just converted into HEX or is it an Alphanumeric ID converted to HEX?

Because when the HEX above is converted to text it has all sorts of weird characters in it that aren't numbers.

Comment: *Anything* can have a representation in that format, thats 20 bytes of *something* - if its not obviously plain text then who knows what it is?  What is the actual problem your facing?

Comment: I would like to generate such ID, and would like to know how its done. Is it hashed or encrypted before...can't figure that out. And whether thats a good way to even do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks like SHA1. Please see  http://www.sha1-online.com enter any random text and press HASH, you will get a 40-character long hex string.

To use with PHP, please see http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sha1.php